# Primary entity manager factory is not selected in Spring

Tags: spring, entitymanager

There are two datasources configured. Primary em factory:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.example.data.postgresql"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgreSqlEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "postgreSqlEntityTransactionManager"
)
public class PostgreSqlJpaConfig {
...
@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean postgreSqlEntityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("postgreSqlDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.example.postgresql").build();
}
```

Secondary em factory:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.example.data.greenplum"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "greenPlumEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "greenPlumEntityTransactionManager"
)
public class GreenPlumJpaConfig {

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean greenPlumEntityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("greenPlumDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.example.greenplum").build();
}
```

Services lays in `com.example.service`. Sometimes they use entity manager, and Spring can't choose between two:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field entityManager in ... required a single bean, but 2 were found:
```

I can manually add a qualifier to the every em injection to make it work,

```
@Autowired
public void setEntityManager(@Qualifier("postgreSqlEntityManagerFactory") EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

but there are 120+ em injections in the app so I hope there should be another way to tell Spring to use the default primary em in all cases where it is not specified explicitly.

Comment: I created a test app with two entities, the same package structure, two pg cloud sources and config. Everything work like a charm. I need an advice where to dig in the big app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the outdated Spring Boot. Upgrade to 2.6.2 solved the issue.